# How to update variable before while loop

Tags: php

I have a variable named post_counter, and I want to get the value of it after it finished the loop, and I want it as the first list item to display. but the problem is the php only read the variable as 0 because the compiler read the codes from top to bottom. how can i update my counter? this is my php code:

```
$post_counter = 0;
<ul>
<?php
$query_post = "SELECT post_date,post_message FROM tbl_posts";
$post_run = mysqli_query($con,$query_post);
echo "<li style = 'text-align:center; cursor:default'><h3>"."New posts".$post_counter."</h3></li>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($post_run))
{
    echo "<li><a class = 'mark_read'>"."mark as read"."</a></li>";
    $post_counter++;
}
?>
</ul>
```

the output of this will be:

```
New posts 0
```

but it should be

```
New posts 5 //since there are 5 rows in my table that will be selected
```

Comment: Since you're using it before you actually loop, it will always print 0. Why not get the `mysqli_num_rows()` of the query and set that for the `"New Posts"` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mysqli_num_rows()`

```
$post_run = mysqli_query($con,$query_post);
$num_posts = mysqli_num_rows($postrun);
echo "<li style = 'text-align:center; cursor:default'><h3>"."New posts".$num_posts ."</h3></li>";
```

Comment: You can't tell the OP to use `mysql_` functions and then say `don't use mysql_ functions`...

Comment: Yes I can. I can tell them how to solve their problem and then I can tell them a better way to do it. They get a solution and learn a better way to do it.

Comment: Then explain how to do it with `mysqli_`.

Comment: this answer does not merit a downvote, and is correct

Comment: agreed with @Ghost it answers the question as stated. +1

Comment: What's funny is the real issue is that they were using mysqli the whole time. I just saw mysql since it is what we see the most here.

Comment: This has been quite the rollercoaster.

Comment: I'm already using mysqli because I read that it is a bad practice to use it nowadays.thank you sir.

Comment: @monkeycoder Glad to see you're doing it the right way!